# Excel Filter Based on column data

Tags: excel, xls

So i have an excel file with many ID and ZIP codes.

[image]

I want to create a way to be able to only show the rows with the zip code starting with BB - the last part of the zip code ignored.

For example, the final result should only show "2   BB1 111" - no other data

Comment: Filter your data. On second column, filter those that start with "BB".

Answer (score 0):

Just filter text start with `BB`. See the below screenshot.

[image]